# How to get a session Object in the ContainerRequest to can use the annotation @RolesAllowed(Role_user)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, servlet-filters

I am building an application using App Engine with Jersey. I would like use the annotation `@RolesAllowed(Role_user)` who permit to create a filter in the request.

The problem is that we need to configure the class `SecurityContextFilter`.

My objective is to get the `id` of the user stored in a session to then check their role directly in the `function : public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request)` of my class `SecurityContextFilter`.

I need to inject `HttpRequest` to get the session, but when I inject it I get an exception `Java.lang.Null`.

I want to get a session Object in the class `ContainerRequest`.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I have find a solution for this issue but I don't know if this is clean: You can inject the HttpRequest directly in the function : isUserInRole(_role)
So I use this and I get my userId by the session then get the role user and I check if that match _role and return true or false.

Comment: I think I have the same problem .. You try to inject the HttpRequest with @Context private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;  .. right? I tried in this way and the httpRequest is null inside the filter

Comment: Yes! It's exactly what I try to do! But I still don't have the response. If you have a solution to this issue can you tell me please.

Comment: nope.. I didn't find anything yet ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty not sure whether you can inject a `HttpServletRequest` on top of the `ContainerRequestFilter` in jersey but you still can do it programmatically instead of using annotations:

```
@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    if(request.isUserInRole("SOME_ROLE")){
    //process some treatement
    }
    return request;
}
```

BR.